# MVC-like UI updates in Javascript/jQuery: best practices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm coming across a bit of an awkward problem.  I have a Web page with quite a few buttons on it that need to be disabled and enabled at various points.  Now if this were a Swing (or any otehr desktop UI interface for that matter), it would be quite trivial: I would simply add listeners for the model changes I was interested in and update the UI accordingly.

This is basic MVC stuff really.

Thing is, I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to handle this nicely in Javascript.  I'm going down a route that will end up with some real spaghetti code where the click listeners for the buttons are updating the UI controls and that's just not going to end well.

**EDIT:** Let me give you a more concreate example.

**Example**

Imagine a screen that lists open orders.  Those orders are presented in a table as each row (order) has multiple attributes against it, such as who is currently managing the order, who made the order, what it's for, when the order was made and the status of the order.

I've done it so you can select one (or more) of these orders by clicking on the rows.  This adds a "selected" class, which changes the styling, much like a list.

As to the behaviour, if a user selects one order then certain actions become available, such as Open Order (to view the details), Take Owneship, Cancel and so on.  The attributes of the order may also affect what actions are available eg if the order is "owned" by somebody else already, certain actions will be disabled.

Some of these options (like opening the order) aren't available if you've selected multiple orders.

Additionally via a background Ajax call the list refreshes with new orders periodically.  The user can also click refresh or can filter the orders (by name, date range and so on) and then reload the orders.  While the orders are reloading certain buttons get disabled.

I was going to do a second example but I think that one is sufficiently complex to illustrate the kind of problem.  Now I've started this by giving various controls classes.  For example, elements with the "select" class might be disabled/enabled/styled when an item is selected.

Now this works reasonably well in simple cases but I'm running into problems where the state of a control depends on multiple conditions.  Also the classes are getting fractured by things like some elements want to be styled, some controls want to be disabled/enabled and in some cases both things need to happen.

In Swing I tended to handdle this kind of thing by having a sort of updateUI() method, which would be called whenever the state of a relevant control or model was changed.  It would then set the state of all the controls explicitly.  Now this is arguably not the most efficient way (eg if you have 30 controls and only need to update one of them it's a bit of a waste) but I found the simplicity was worth it.  The alternative was that controls/models ended up with too information about what controls they depended on or those that depended on them.  It go tmessy from a coupling point of view.

But I have no such (obvious) mechanism in Javascript.  Inobtrusive Javascript as advocated by jQuery is great because it stops random code snippets being littered throughout your code.  But I need to go a step further nad have some way of managing the complexity of this (because it is quite a complex screen and will only get more complex).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve your sanity, use a state machine.

You don't really give details about what your UI does, so I'll make up an example. Let's say you have a file upload page. The user should be able to select a file, click an upload button, and then be returned to the page they came from, when uploading is complete. So you could have three states, "SelectFile", "Uploading", "Finished". In the "SelectFile" state, controls should be enabled to allow the user to select a file. In the "Uploading" state, these control should be disabled, and the user should see a progress indicator. In the "Finished" state, the user should be redirected.

Of course, it sounds like your case is more complicated, but the same ideas will apply. You may need more than one state machine, if portions of user interface interact. That's fine.

When you want to change the enabled/disabled elements on the user interface, you just change the state of the state machine. The state machine itself tells the various user interface controls to update themselves based on the current state. You can use a Bharani's (good, up voted) suggestion of using classes to do this. Or whatever mechanism works for you.

The nice thing is that the controls no longer interact with each other. They only interact with the state machine. So you get rid of all the cases where states bounce around incorrectly or endlessly recurse.

Comment: I have been doing some UI's with javascript recently that are really brittle and difficult to change. They seem to be crying out to be modelled as state machines, so this is probably going to be the starting point for js based ui's for me going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Assign specific class names to the divs. That way even if they overlap in functionality you can simply keep adding class names to the div and because of the chain nature of jquery all registered event handlers will be executed.

For controlling form elements during ajax call - you can add ajaxStart and ajaxEnd or you can use ajaxComplete and handle all your code inside the callbacks.

Comment: I believe that this solution is precisely the fear of @cletus. this leads to spaghetti code. Unless I don't understand (which means you might want to clarify a bit).

Answer (score 0):

I think i get your problem. I have worked on such screens before and i always ended up refactoring to structure the code better. But at times it will be easier if you could re-organize the functionality itself so that you don't have to handle all things in one place. I think GUI should also be treated like a function - do one thing and one thing well.

Answer (score 0):

I think data modeling is important for JavaScript apps. I am working on this scheduling project for medical clinics and I have a JSON data structure that models chairs/patients in an office. Ember updates the views (UI widgets) automatically when the business logic changes in the models. So right off the bat a lot of sphagetti code is eliminated. If you are doing something graphically intense with user interaction it is almost a crime not to use an existing MVC pattern or to create your own MVC JS classes. The structured discipline is off putting at first but when you see later how it lowers your blood pressure and makes maintenance so much more enjoyable it is worth it. I wouldn't use it for simple one-off projects if they are small. It is better for medium complexity or advanced complexity. Anything that will take me more than a week I will use Ember. I have used knockout.js and Angular and I really like Ember with its Handlebars templating syntax. Easy on the eyes and efficient.